# Check if ISO 8601 date older than 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601

I'm a little surprised. haven't found any answers on google (maybe I'm searching wrong?)

My question:
How can i check if this `2018-05-21T00:04:01.891Z` date older than 5 minutes?

Comment: I'm surprised you only searched for 1 minute 53 seconds before posting the question :p

Comment: or I just copied the date before I wrote the post ...

Comment: It was a joke :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subtract the date from the current date, and check if the difference (which is in milliseconds) is greater than `5 * 60 * 1000`, which is 5 minutes in ms.

```
(new Date() - new Date("2018-05-21T00:04:01.891Z")) > 5 * 60 * 1000
```

Comment: by the time you posted the answer, it was only just true :p