# dayjs: date supplied from mongodb is at least 5 minutes old

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I'm using dayjs and trying to figure out how to check if a date is at least 5 minutes ago.

Here is an example of a date: 2021-11-04T12:20:46.485Z

Its probably some subtracting and adding 5 somewhere but the MongoDB format and dayjs is somewhat confusing.

Ref ? https://day.js.org/docs/en/query/is-after

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if ISO 8601 date older than 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440470/check-if-iso-8601-date-older-than-5-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

Using vanilla JS date object, you can find the difference in minutes between two dates.
Example:

```
const today = new Date(); // This represents the current date + time

const difference = parseInt(
   (Math.abs(today.getTime() - OTHERDATEOBJECT.getTime()) / (1000 * 60)) % 60);

// Handling the difference
if (difference > 5) {
   // Do something if it was at least 5 minutes ago
} else {
   // If not 5 minutes ago, do something else
}
```

If you are passing it a date string, you may need to create a new date object with it before you can compare it to your "today" date object

like so:

```
const difference = parseInt(
   (Math.abs(today.getTime() - (new Date(OTHERDATE)).getTime()) / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
```